# Why does my TCSH prompt change after cd?

Tags: shell, shell-script, tcsh

My .cshrc file contains the following:

```
set prompt = "%{\033[0;32m%}%S%B\! <%~> :%b%s %{\033[0m%}"
```

Each time I `cd` out of my home directory, the prompt formatting resets to display:

```
33 /~/newdirectory/ :
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the `precmd` and/or `postcmd` special aliases set? Is there an alias with the name `cd`?

Comment: Thanks. That feedback worked. I searched my .aliasrc file and found an alias for `cd` that sets to a new prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@manatwork's suggestion to check any aliases was correct. I found an alias for cd in one of my .aliasrc files. For anyone who encounters this problem try grepping your home directory for:

<strike>`egrep "alias cd" *`</strike>

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs grep 'alias *cd'`

If you find an `alias cd` followed by a `set prompt =`, that's the culprit.

Comment: doing `which cd ` also gives the same.. infact it's more accurate.